# Calculate the amount to pay based on time difference in 2 textboxes VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh4g8.png)

I want to get the amount to pay based on time difference of the time in and time out. 
example. Time In is : 7:00:00
         Time Out is : 13:00:00
         The difference is 6 hrs
and lets say that the per hour rate is 10.00, so the amount should be 60.00 
thanks! im using vb.net

what im trying to do is like this.

```
Private Const Format As String = "HH:mm:ss"

'this is the code i used to get the time in
Private Sub btnTimeIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTimeIn.Click
     TextboxTimeIn.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(Format)
End Sub

'this is the time out
Private Sub btnTimeOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTimeOut.Click
    TextboxTimeOut.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(Format)

    'this is what is use to get the time difference
    txtAmount.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(TextboxTimeOut.Text).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(TextboxTimeIn.Text)).ToString()     
End Sub
```

but instead of showing the time difference, i want to show the amount in the txtAmount. example

if timeDifference <= 60mins , then
  txtAmount = 10

else timeDifference > 60mins , then
txtAmount = 20

Comment: Please provide a minimum verifiable example of your attempt:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Im sorry because I am new to coding. you can see what im trying to say in the picture attached. thanks

Comment: you can see that i have the time in and time out. when i click the time in, it will go to time in textbox. and when i click time out, it calculates the time difference of the two. but what i want is, instead of displaying the time difference in the amount, i want to see the convertion in it to price. which is per hour is 10php.

Comment: Do you have any code relating to your problem? For instance, when you click Time In how are your displaying the time?

Comment: please see the my edited question. thank you

Comment: If you made a new variable with the time difference then the pseudo-code at the end of your question would work.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it please?

Answer (score 0):

You want to know 3 things:

1. How much time passed between checkin and checkout
2. How many hours is that
3. Hom much will this cost

These points could be calculated in only one line, but for the sake of clarity we'll clear them one by one:

```
'let's use some more variables to make this easier
Private Const Format As String = "HH:mm:ss"
Private checkin As DateTime
Private checkout As DateTime
Private rate As Integer = 10

'now with variables!
Private Sub btnTimeIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTimeIn.Click
    checkin = Now
    TextboxTimeIn.Text = checkin.ToString(Format)
End Sub

Private Sub btnTimeOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTimeOut.Click
    checkout = Now
    TextboxTimeOut.Text = checkout.ToString(Format)

    'First we check for an amount of hours, then we add one if they overstayed
    Dim timeStayed As Integer = checkout.Hour - checkin.Hour
    If TimeStayed.Minute > 0 Then timeStayed += 1

    'Notice the use of a variable so you can tweak your rates easily
    txtAmount.Text = (timeStayed * rate).ToString
End Sub
```

What you need to remember here is:

1. Make things easier on you. Don't convert everything all the time.
2. Follow your own pseudocode. You already knew what to do. Do it.
3. I used Integers for money... this is bad! You should change this as soon as possible, so your numbers can have decimals! (also you should format the txtAmount as money)
4. Have fun!